# Flutter Blue Plus on WearOS to BLE

Tags: flutter, arduino, bluetooth-lowenergy, wear-os

Flutter Blue Plus plugin not working on WearOS.

I was wondering if anyone has any experience with connecting WearOS using the Flutter Blue Plus plugin to an Arduino Nano BLE. I've used the plugin for connecting my phone to the Arduino Nano which worked fine.

However, I'm creating trying to create a WearOS app right now and the Bluetooth LE plugin is not detecting any devices at all. I'm using the example code provided by the Flutter Blue Plus plugin for reference which can be found here https://github.com/boskokg/flutter_blue_plus.

I am also using the Wear plugin which can be found here https://pub.dev/packages/wear.

I would appreciate it if anyone can help me.

Comment: Are you testing your WearOS app on a real device?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.